# Create member function according to variable value in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

The original code is too complicated so I abstract the problem as following:

```
class A {
  public:
    A (int p): _p{p} {}

    float computeA (float a) {
      if (_p == 0)
        return 0.1f + expf(a);
      else if (_p == 1)
        return 0.2f + sqrtf(a);
      else if (_p == 2)
        return 0.3f + sinf(a);
      return 0.4f +cosf(a);
    }

    float accumulate() {
      ...
      for(...) {
        int temp = computeA();
        // other calculations...
      }
      ...
    }

    ...

  private:
    const int _p;
};
```

**_p** is a constant member in **A**, and can be only either 0, 1, 2, or 3. The calculation in **computeA()** depends on the value of **_p**. Since **_p** is already known when creating **A**, I wonder if there is a proper way to avoid the "if" conditions in the code.

Polymorphism is not practical (or it is?) for just changing one line of code for each child class (**A** has a dozen of member functions, and only **computeA()** makes a difference). Another issue might be the performance since the simple **computeA()** is frequently called in a large loop of the heavy **accumulate()**. Would overhead of polymorphic function calls become unacceptable?

Thanks,

Comment: How about computing and storing `A` during construction and ignoring `_p`?

Comment: You can always swap an `if` or a `switch` with an extra level of indirection (whether a virtual function, a good old plain function pointer, or whatever). Performance should be pretty close but only a benchmark in your specific environment could tell for sure.

Comment: Please, note that including `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>` you'll have the right overload of those function, e.g [`float std::exp(float arg);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple function pointer:

```
float compute0(float a) { return 0.1f + expf(a); }
float compute1(float a) { return 0.2f + sqrtf(a); }
float compute2(float a) { return 0.3f + sinf(a); }
float compute3(float a) { return 0.4f + cosf(a); }

class A {
  public:
    typedef float (*functype)(float);

    A (int p) {
      switch (p) {
        case 0:  _func = &compute0; break;
        case 1:  _func = &compute1; break;
        case 2:  _func = &compute2; break;
        default: _func = &compute3; break;
    }

    float computeA (float a) {
      return _func(a);
    }

    ...

  private:
    functype _func;
};
```

Or, if you want to be fancy with it, you can use lambdas instead:

```
class A {
  public:
    A (int p) {
      switch (p) {
        case 0:  _func = [](float a) { return 0.1f + std::exp(a); }; break;
        case 1:  _func = [](float a) { return 0.2f + std::sqrt(a); }; break;
        case 2:  _func = [](float a) { return 0.3f + std::sin(a); }; break;
        default: _func = [](float a) { return 0.4f + std::cos(a); }; break;
    }

    float computeA (float a) {
      return _func(a);
    }

    ...

  private:
    std::function<float(float)> _func;
};
```

Alternatively, let the code that creates the `A` object decide what value and function to compute with:

```
class A {
  public:
    typedef float (*functype)(float);

    A (float value, functype func) :
      _value(value), _func(func)
    }

    float computeA (float a) {
      return _value + _func(a);
    }

    ...

  private:
    const float _value;
    const functype _func;
};
```

```
A a1(0.1f, &expf);
A a2(0.2f, &sqrtf);
A a3(0.3f, &sinf);
A a4(0.4f, &cosf);
```

Or:

```
class A {
  public:
    using functype = std::function<float(float)>;

    A (float value, functype func) :
      _value(value), _func(func)
    }

    float computeA (float a) {
      return _value + _func(a);
    }

    ...

  private:
    const float _value;
    const functype _func;
};
```

```
A a1(0.1f, std::exp);
A a2(0.2f, std::sqrt);
A a3(0.3f, std::sin);
A a4(0.4f, std::cos);
```

Or, use polymorphism, and let the caller decide which sub-class to use (or even create its own sub-class for custom calculations):

```
class A {
  public:
    A () {}

    virtual float computeA (float a) = 0;

    ...
};

class A_exp : public A {
  public:
    float computeA (float a) override { return 0.1f + std::exp(a); }
};

class A_sqrt : public A {
  public:
    float computeA (float a) override { return 0.2f + std::sqrt(a); }
};

class A_sin : public A {
  public:
    float computeA (float a) override { return 0.3f + std::sin(a); }
};

class A_cos : public A {
  public:
    float computeA (float a) override { return 0.4f + std::cos(a); }
};
```

```
A_exp a1;
A_sqrt a2;
A_sin a3;
A_cos a4;
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Polymorphism is not practical (or it is?) for just changing one line of code for each child class...

Sure it is.  The base type has all of the same code, except for `computeA()`, which becomes pure virtual:

```
float computeA(float) = 0;
```

Then each base only overrides that one method.

Note that if indirect function call overhead is acceptable (see the following section) then you could instead have your constructor take an `std::function<float(float)>` and let the caller pass in `expf`, `sqrtf`, etc. as appropriate.  This way you don't need child classes, and the class consumer isn't limited to four functions -- nor are they limited to just functions (functors become viable).

> Would overhead of polymorphic function calls become unacceptable?

That's a great question, and it's one that you should answer for *your specific use case* by benchmarking both options.

---

A few suggestions if you stick with the conditional approach:

- `_p` should more properly be a `class enum` type so that you don't have magic numbers floating around in your code.
- Consider using `switch` instead of `if`. As it is typically implemented as a computed-goto, it has the potential to be slightly faster. (A smart compiler might optimize your multiple conditionals into a single computed-goto, however.)

Comment: I would expect that `std::function<float(float)>` is slower than indirect function call overhead, not faster. Internally it uses indirect function calls, but now you also have allocations taking place.

Comment: @MooingDuck For a function pointer, the small function optimization should elide any allocations.